# How to permanently disable Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and USB Mass Storage in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-wifi, android-bluetooth

I'm working on an Android app which requires to disable WiFi, Bluetooth and Mass Storage options.

I've seen some apps like [Timeriffic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfray.timeriffic) and [ProfileScheduler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wetpalm.ProfileScheduler). These apps will help disable the certain features like bluetooth and WiFi. But they will only change put them on/off.

In my case I want to completely disable them and then they are not available for user.

I would like to know is there any API in Android which will allow us to completely disable the  these features???

Comment: Why would you want to do that?? As far as I know, you cannot do that, unless ofcourse you are a OEM, in which case you wouldn't do it with an android app.

Comment: @AnudeepBulla I'm working on a security app which requires to do so...

Comment: permanently as in ? till next boot? or forever ?

Comment: Permanently would actually serve the purpose, but I would like to know is there a way we can disable them till next boot??

Comment: Security though an app is done via the Device Administrator API (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).
With that you can disable the camera and enforce passwords and storage encryption. I don't think you can disable the items you want with that at the moment though.

Comment: @prince I need to likewise disable WiFi and Bluetooth. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a perfect solution... but for a work around, you can listen for state of wifi. Use [ConnectionManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

Whenever wifi is turned on.. You can disconnect it via code..

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

:D

Answer (score 3):

These steps are to Disable WiFi:

1. Open ES File Explorer and give Root access
2. Go to system folder and open Build.prop using RB Text Editor (i recommend you to backup original file)
3. Remove the below mentioned lines in Build.prop

```html
wifi.interface=
wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=
```

4. save it and reboot!!

You can notice that WiFi buttons are no longer in use!!

More details are [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/root-permanently-disable-wifi-t3057599) :)

Comment: What if I don't have those properties in `build.prop` I don't even have the `Build.prop` file (cap sensitive).

Running an Asus Zenfon 5 rooted with Kitkat 4.4.2

Comment: There are no such entries in `build.prop` on Moto G 2014.